# ActionScript 3 - How to target textbox inside movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, colors, textfield

I have a movie clip called radio and flashlight. Inside the movieclip, there is a text box with words inside. The instance name of the textbox inside radio is called 'radioText' and the instance name of the textbox inside flashlight is called 'flashlightText'. I want the color of the text to turn white when hovering over the movieclip.

The code below works for changing radioText but not flashlightText:

```
var containers = [radio, flashlight];

for (var i:int = 0; i<containers.length; i++) {
    containers[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hOver);
}

var whiteFont:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
whiteFont.color = 0xFFFFFF;


function hOver(evt:Event):void {
    evt.currentTarget.radioText.setTextFormat(whiteFont); //change radioText's color
}
```

what I want to do is instead of

```
evt.currentTarget.radioText.setTextFormat(whiteFont);
```

, I want to do somthing like

```
evt.currentTarget.(currentTarget.name + 'Text').setTextFormat(whiteFont);
```

but that doesn't work for obvious reasons. Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few good ways to implement what you are asking, what you do really depends on how you are setting up your objects.

For example, your pseudo code:

```
evt.currentTarget.(currentTarget.name + 'Text').setTextFormat(whiteFont);
```

...could be implemented if you named all your child text fields identically OR if you named them accordingly to some convention (for this example I set a name for the parent and a similar name for the child). So let's assume your container has the name "container" and has a `TextField` child named "containerText". It would look something like this:

```
private function hOver(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var n:String = evt.currentTarget.name;
    evt.currentTarget.getChildByName( n + "Text" ).setTextFormat( whiteFont );
}
```

This is now dependent on following a naming convention, which may or may not be ideal. So what might be an even better and more generic way to handle this? You can setup a class for your container object and have a `TextField` property there. For Example:

```
class myContainer extends Sprite {
    public var textField:TextField;

    public function myContainer():void {
        textField = new TextField();
        addChild(textField);
    }
}
```

Pretty basic, but now if you added all the listeners to types of myContainer your event function could look like this:

```
private function hOver(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    evt.currentTarget[ "textField" ].setTextFormat( whiteFont );
}
```

Which is probably more what you are looking for. This version allows you to grab the "textField" property of the object you applied the listener to, in this case that property would essentially be your radioText/flashlightText.

Ok so lastly, and the least favorable way to do this, assumes all you care about is that the object has a child of type `TextField`, it has no logical naming convention, and we are not sure what index it is at in the display list. You would have to do it something like this:

```
private function hOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var i:int;
    var displayObj:DisplayObjectContainer = e.currentTarget as DisplayObjectContainer;

    for ( ; i < displayObj.numChildren; i++ ) {
        var obj:* = displayObj.getChildAt( i );
        if ( obj is TextField ) {
            obj.setTextFormat( whiteFont );
        }
    }
}
```

That is also the slowest way of reaching your child object. This should cover all the bases, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with?

```
DisplayObjectContainer(evt.currentTarget)[evt.currentTarget.name + 'Text'].setTextFormat(whiteFont);
```

Comment: This will not work, I can tell you from an eyeball glance that evt.currentTarget.name + "Text" will not be a property of the event object current target unless that object is a class (that inherits DisplayObjectContainer obviously) containing the textField member (as I posted in my above answer).

Comment: I see. Should use getChildByName with type casting like:    `var parent:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
parent.graphics.beginFill(0xCCCCCC);
parent.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
parent.name = "parent";
parent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:Event):void {
 var txt:TextField = DisplayObjectContainer(event.currentTarget).getChildByName(event.currentTarget.name + 'Text') as TextField;
 txt.setTextFormat(new TextFormat());
});
addChild(parent);
var txtfield:TextField = new TextField();
txtfield.name = "parentText";
parent.addChild(txtfield);`

Comment: Yes that has been stated in my answer as well. Although there no reason to cast to a DisplayObjectContainer considering currentTarget is an object.